# Importing and Splitting CSV input, Need helping reading only first character of

Tags: java, arrays, excel, csv

Working on a class project, having trouble with the data after it is read into an array.

In the excel spreadsheet, I need to read straight down a column paying attention to only the first digit in each block. When i split the column it is a continuous string with no space so I can't figure out how to only count the first digit as opposed to counting each digit (as the code does now).
Example: (11, 20, 296) is split, becoming "1120296"

```
        final int[] benfordLaw = {0, 30, 18, 13, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5};
        int[] actualPrecent = new int[10];
        int benfordScore = 0;
        float[] countForNum = new float[10];
        float totalCount = 0;

        //This while loop will read through each line of the file
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

            // This statement reads in the next line of the file.
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            String[] values = line.split(",(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*+\"){2})*+[^\"]*+$)");


            //12-15 is the column #'s
            for (int i = 12; i < 15; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length(); j++) {
                    char charA = values[i].charAt(j);
                    for (int k = 1; k <= 9; ++k){
                        char compare = (char)(k + '0');
                        if (charA == compare) {
                            ++countForNum[k];
                            ++totalCount;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I didn't totally get what is your question, but hope it helps

Example: (11, 20, 296) is split, becoming "1120296" => If you only want to get the 11 in the text

Read Line and get the string
Sol 1. ) 
a) Remove the first and last char
b) Split.Text and trim it.
c) get the first one

Sol 2. )
Use RegEx and get the first element 
ex RegEx.) ([0-9]*),

Good Luck